# ActionScripts3 read XML from Server issue

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have a sample XML on **LocalHost** and I wrote some code to read it's data, it works fine but when i uploaded to **Byethost** server it works on **web-browser** but return error in **Adobe Animate**.

XML Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>

    <D1>1</D1>
    <D2>2</D2>
    <D3>3</D3>

</Data>
```

AS3 Codes:

```
import flash.events.Event; 
import flash.net.URLLoader; 

var myXML:XML = new XML(); 
var XML_URL:String = "http://example.com/api/data.xml"; 
var myXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL); 
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(myXMLURL); 
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded); 

function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void 
{ 
    myXML = XML(myLoader.data); 
    trace(myXML.D1); 
    trace(myXML.D2); 
    trace(myXML.D3); 

}
```

Output when reading XML in **localhost** from ActionScripts3:

```
1 2 3
```

Output when using **Web-Browser**:

```
1 2 3
```

Output when reading XML in server (**byet.host**) from ActionScripts3:

```
TypeError: Error #1085: The element type "d.length;f++)e+=(16" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</d.length;f++)e+=(16>".
```

Message from Debug mode:

```
Attempting to launch and connect to Player using URL E:\PROJECTS\1. ANIMATE\XML\RECOVER_xml.swf
[SWF] E:\PROJECTS\1. ANIMATE\XML\RECOVER_xml.swf - 1802 bytes after decompression
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
Connection to http://example.com/api/data.xml halted - not permitted from file:///E|/PROJECTS/1.%20ANIMATE/XML/RECOVER%5Fxml.swf
-- Untrusted local SWFs may not contact the Internet.
SecurityError: Error #2028: Local-with-filesystem SWF file file:///E|/PROJECTS/1.%20ANIMATE/XML/RECOVER%5Fxml.swf cannot access Internet URL http://example.com/api/data.xml.
    at flash.net::URLStream/load()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/load()
    at flash.net::URLLoader()
    at RECOVER_xml_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[RECOVER_xml_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:7]
Cannot display source code at this location.
```

**Solution**:

```
*Free hosts doesn't support direct access to files. It is possible to use google drive for access directly to a file and read it's content.*

This site helped me to solve this problem:

http://www.syncwithtech.org/p/direct-download-link-generator.html
```

Comment: It seems there is a security error, my target is multiplatform AIR application.

Comment: How can i solve this permission error and make this app trusted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a security violation. If you intend to test your application locally you are to go and allow it with global security settings: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

If you want to load XML from domain B with application from domain A you should allow it with crossdomain policy placed on domain B: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e08.html

Comment: I changed security in publish setting and it works. Thanks.

Comment: I published app for AIR desktop it works, In android AIR publish setting i checked all permissions in permission TAB but still that security error exist, what I must do?

Comment: Hmmm, did you check "access network" right on the permissions tab (last one on Android Publish Settings panel)?

Comment: TypeError: Error #1085: The element type "d.length;f++)e+=(16" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</d.length;f++)e+=(16>".

Comment: Can you give a direct link to your XML on the web?

Comment: It work in Animate CC Test mode of Android AIR, after publish and install on android phone it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, I understand your problem. But "http://example.com/api/data.xml" is not your XML. I wanted to test **your** XML and see what happens.

Comment: again nothing work, not on desktop not on android. error #1085 again...

Comment: Place trace(myLoader.data) into the handler. The site returns some weird HTML page instead of your XML (yes, I know the link returns XML in browser just fine). So, it's problem with the website, not with your code or security.

Comment: I'm using this this new URL and just AIR packages not SWF.

Comment: I just added "trace(myXML)" to codes and again everything works in Test mode, whats happened?

Comment: And still android apk file doesn't show anything in android device, it just work on emulator.

Comment: As I told above. The site returns your XML or something completely different - randomly. Pick another file hosting.

Comment: Again that error occurred. it's related to host. do you know a free host without this problem?

Comment: Thanks for everything.

Comment: Google Drive? https://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/

Comment: Thanks for your useful suggest.

Answer (score 1):

First I would put a breakpoint at the first line of `xmlLoaded` method and start debug session `Debug->Debug`. 
Looks like you're getting malformed xml data, so in debug mode check `myLoader.data` - it should give you an answer

Comment: thanks for your suggest, it helped me to find correct error.